# Rails How to get latitude and longitude from string address and put it on google map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

Here's user story:

User enters address: Paris, France. Then I would like to display google map center on Paris with one movable marker. Then user point with marker to its exact location and clicks save. Address string and map coordinates are saved to database.

After some search I know I can display google map with variuos gems: cartographer for example. My question is how to get coordinates or how to pass address to cartographer so it centers map in Paris?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree, geokit is pretty useful...you can do things like:

```
require 'geokit'
include GeoKit::Geocoders

coords = MultiGeocoder.geocode(location)
puts coords.lat
puts coords.lng
```

Where location is a string location (like an address).  It works pretty well.

You can ALSO reverse geocode, which pulls a string address out of a lat/lng coordinate pair. Pretty spiffy.

Comment: I am getting this error "uninitialized constant GeoKit (NameError)" even i have installed Geokit....Any suggestions ..thanks in advance

Comment: me as well I think the gem is old

Answer (score 11):

Another geocoder option for Ruby is Geocoder: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

```
  location = Geocoder.search( ... )
  location[0].latitude
  location[0].longitude
```

Comment: Geocoder is really useful. But lately I am getting "query limit reached" error. But I am way under my limit.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the gem and plugin [geokit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/). It does exactly what you are looking for and more.