# uninitialized constant Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a ruby app that pinpoints your location given your ip address. I have run into a road block though. I've already searched on this site, but the solutions I've already found are too general.

Here's the error:

```
uninitialized constant Place::IpGeocoder (NameError)
```

And the code I'm developing:

```
require 'socket'
require 'geocoder'
require 'geokit'


class Place

  def get_location

  ip = UDPSocket.open {|s| s.connect("64.233.187.99", 1); s.addr.last}
  location = IpGeocoder.geocode(ip.to_s())
  end

end

me=Place.new
me.get_location
```

I already installed the gems. Do I need to create a instance of it or something like in java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do, as below as per the doc [`Geokit::Geocoders::IpGeocoder`](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/a/abuiles-geokit-1.6.1/Geokit/Geocoders/IpGeocoder.html) .

```
Geokit::Geocoders::IpGeocoder.geocode(ip.to_s())
```

The class `IpGeocoder` is defined inside the module `Geokit::Geocoders`. So to access the class you need to use full path to that class, which is `Geokit::Geocoders::IpGeocoder`, using scope resolution operator `::`.

Comment: oh ok i see now so if I were to do something like the soltion to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889599/rails-how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-from-string-address-and-put-it-on-google it will sort of be the same thing correct. With the include and MultiGeocoder

Comment: @CalvinJones It means full path you need to give.. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's called namespacing. Essentially what you've done is tried to access the `IpGeocoder` constant that is located in your `Place` class. Except you didn't define a constant there. You have to tell ruby where to locate the `IpGeocoder` constant by giving it a direction. (Clarification: in ruby class names are constants)

The class and method are probably declared in the source code like this:

```
module Geokit
  module Geocoders
    class IpGeocoder
    def geocode(ip)
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see here, to reference the method in the `IpGeocoder` class, you need to tell your class so way to get to it. Arup has described that succinctly.

Comment: ok thanks so much for clarify that up now I totally understand the concept now god bless you sir thanks again for the help