# Save requested geolocation in rails with geocoder to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-geocoder

I'm working at a social network project in rails and we need to show a "map of dreams".

Technically, we want to display all our user geolocation (for security reasons, without much preciseness) at map as "dreams map" in our city).
I'm using devise for users administration and I already installed geocoder gem.

I want to know how could I save the requested (HTML5 geolocation service/functionality, I guess...) to database and display it at a map.
I've been trying a few days ago but I can only show the location if users fill their country/city fields. Note.: Our app doesn't has a Users controller.

**UPDATE:**

I'm getting only the reference to the entire city with IP address request from the last_sign_in_ip column. I've read that request by HTML5/geolocation with geocoder uses MAC address of the network card and it displays a more accurate location...

***I need at least the neighborhood (with a pin in the map) from requested geolocation to the user.***

Comment: you can also get the location of user from requested IP if user didn't fill country & City fields

Comment: That's the way in which I'm working right now, but IP in most cases only  gives me the city...

Comment: you use still get lat long from city name as well look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889599/rails-how-to-get-latitude-and-longitude-from-string-address-and-put-it-on-google

Comment: I updated the question. I don't need lat and long from city name, I need at least the neighbourhood from requested geolocation to the user.
RIght now I'm able to obtain lat and long from CIty, Country by concatenating that field after user sign up at form.